# Changing months to seasons

Tags: r, label

I am working in R. I have a dataframe where I have sampling date, the month of that sampling date in full name, and water temperature. Below is a sample of my data frame.

```
   Date           Month       Temperature
   2016-07-01     July        13
   2017-01-08     January     5
   2018-09-19     September   11
   2019-10-24     October     9
```

What I want to do is use the month and create a new column in which the season is labeled. For the purposes of this project I am classifying Jan-Mar as Winter, Apr-Jun as Spring, Jul-Sep as Summer, Oct-Dec as Fall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option where we create a named vector and use that to match and replace the 'Month' to create new column

```
library(dplyr)
nm1 <- setNames(rep(c("Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Fall"),
        each = 3), month.name)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(Season = nm1[Month])
```

-output

```
#         Date     Month Temperature Season
#1 2016-07-01      July          13 Summer
#2 2017-01-08   January           5 Winter
#3 2018-09-19 September          11 Summer
#4 2019-10-24   October           9   Fall
```

---

Or it can be done in `base R`

```
df1$Season = nm1[df1$Month]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("2016-07-01", "2017-01-08", "2018-09-19", 
"2019-10-24"), Month = c("July", "January", "September", "October"
), Temperature = c(13L, 5L, 11L, 9L)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume the input shown reproducibly in the Note at the end where the `Date` field is of class `Date` -- convert it as shown in the Note if not.  The following then shows a variety of approaches.  The first two convert the `Date` column (which seems easier) and the last two convert the `Month` column.

**1) yearqtr**  Convert `Date` to a `yearqtr` object.  Using `cycle` on that will give the quarter (1, 2, 3 or 4) and then we can index the quarter number into `seasons`.

```
library(zoo)

seasons <- c("Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Fall")
transform(DF, Season = seasons[cycle(as.yearqtr(Date))])
##         Date     Month Temperature Season
## 1 2016-07-01      July          13 Summer
## 2 2017-01-08   January           5 Winter
## 3 2018-09-19 September          11 Summer
## 4 2019-10-24   October           9   Fall
```

If just using the quarter number is ok then this one-liner would be sufficient.

```
transform(DF, Season = cycle(as.yearqtr(Date)))
```

**2) quarters**  We can also do it using only base R by using the `quarters` function which returns `Q1`, `Q2`, `Q3` or `Q4` as a string given a date.  In that case we need to ensure that `Seasons.Q` uses those names in order to use it to do a lookup.

```
Seasons.Q <- c(Q1 = "Winter", Q2 = "Spring", Q3 = "Summer", Q4 = "Fall")
transform(DF, Season = Seasons.Q[quarters(Date)])
```

If using Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4 instead of the names is ok then we could reduce it to this one-liner:

```
transform(DF, Season = quarters(Date))
```

**3) match**  The above used the Date field. We can also use the Month field as our input converting it to a month number 1, 2, 3, ..., 12 and then converting that to a quarter number which can be indexed into `seasons` defined above.

```
transform(DF, Season = seasons[(match(Month, month.name) - 1) %/% 3 + 1])
```

If a quarter number rather than season name is sufficient then we can reduce it to this one-liner:

```
transform(DF, Season = (match(DF$Month, month.name) - 1) %/% 3 + 1)
```

**4) Date formatting**  We can also use Date formatting to convert the Month to a Date and then use `quarters` and a lookup into `Seasons.Q`.

```
transform(DF, Season = Seasons.Q[quarters(as.Date(paste(DF$Month, "001"), "%B %y%d"))])
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
 Date           Month       Temperature
   2016-07-01     July        13
   2017-01-08     January     5
   2018-09-19     September   11
   2019-10-24     October     9"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
DF$Date <- as.Date(DF$Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like so:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(season = lubridate::quarter(Date)) %>% 
  mutate(season = case_when(
    season == 1 ~ 'Winter',
    season == 2 ~ 'Spring',
    season == 3 ~ 'Summer',
    season == 4 ~ 'Fall'
  ))
#>         Date     Month Temperature season
#> 1 2016-07-01      July          13 Summer
#> 2 2017-01-08   January           5 Winter
#> 3 2018-09-19 September          11 Summer
#> 4 2019-10-24   October           9   Fall
```

or with one line less:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(season = case_when(
    Month %in% c('January', 'February', 'March') ~ 'Winter',
    Month %in% c('April', 'May', 'June') ~ 'Sring',
    Month %in% c('August', 'September', 'July') ~ 'Summer',
    Month %in% c('October', 'November', 'December') ~ 'Fall'
  ))
```